# Может ли метод onAttach() привести к memory leak?

Tags: java, android

Всегда исползую такую практику

```
private MyCallBack mCallBack;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context iC) {
super.onAttach(iC);
try{
mCallBack=(MyCallBack) iC;
}catch(Exeption e){...}
}
```

Но согласно комментам под этим ответом есть возможность сделать memory leak

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24881447/5709159

Это значит, что нужно обнулять где то этот колбэк

Вопрос - насколько вероятна такая ситуация, что действительно будет memory leak и если да то правильно ли обнулять этот колбэк в `onDetach()`

Можно допустим вместо того, чтоб обнулять сслыку, сделать ее weak ссылкой?

Comment: Обнулять колбэки на `onDetach()` - нормальная практика. Без этого (например, при пересоздании активности) возможно пложение сущностей и memory leak

Comment: @Jarvis_J а можно допустим вместо того, чтоб обнулять сслыку, сделать ее weak ссылкой. Мне кажется это тоже будет нормально работать.

Comment: даже не знаю, мне кажется это лишним. Я обнуляю в `onDetach()` )